# Не устанавливается библиотека insightface в pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, модули

Я нашел на github [проект по замене лиц](https://github.com/s0md3v/roop). Я все библиотеки к проекту доустановил кроме insightface. Когда я устанавливал ее там была ошибка:

`ERROR: Could not build wheels for insightface, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

И когда я запускал была ошибка:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'insightface'`

Пожалуйста, помогите мне разобраться с этой ошибкой

Comment: Заранее спасибо!